# Accessing and Displaying JSON Object with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I'm trying to access an object in JSON with AngularJS, and display the values. I have done this when I create an array in JSON but this time I want to show an example with an object. This is my code:

My JSON File

```
{ "user": {
"Name":"Ben", 
"City":"New York"}}
```

My angular app

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

    app.controller('jsonObjectExample', function($scope, $http) {
      $http.get("jsonobject.json").then(function (response) {
          $scope.myData = response.data.user;
      });
    });
```

My HTML

```
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="jsonObjectExample"> 
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="x in myData">
          {{ x.Name + ', ' + x.City }}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Here is a link to these files on plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/uBRf99AjYH9zX0WuHsW3?p=preview

Can someone explain where I'm going wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Check the updated plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/a2czVDmeW0asDS7p5COk?p=preview

Comment: Doesn't that make it into an array instead of an object? I want to access an object just as an example.

Comment: The response you are getting from jsonobject.json is an object and not an array. Hence you have to access an object this way in your HTML. If the response is an array then you can use ng-repeat for iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the ng-repeat. `myData` is object, not an array so no need to use the `ng-repeat`

```
  <body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="jsonObjectExample"> 
      <ul>
        <li >
          {{ myData.Name + ', ' + myData.City }}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
```

[Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/QJb1CFZDyrMENis3G4w3?p=preview)

Comment: @user3305894 no prob make sure to check as answer if this helped

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ng-repeat make sure the json which you are parsing should give some array value.

you can correct your json like:

```
{ "user": [{
"Name":"Ben", 
"City":"New York"}]}
```

Other codes are working fine. Please check [this](https://plnkr.co/edit/dMewxXGXtKR9LxKRMJi0?p=preview)